# using $$ in execute statement of Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a function block like

```
DO $$
DECLARE tran_year RECORD;
BEGIN
   FOR tran_year IN SELECT * FROM tbale1 loop
       EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT unique_cons$$aaf1c86 UNIQUE (samplecol)';
   END LOOP;
END $$;
```

in Postgres, when trying to execute this block, I face an issue saying that ERROR: `syntax error at or near "aaf1c86"`.
I also have the need to use `$$` in constraint name. Any idea of overcoming this error

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) you can use any character sequence between the `$` signs if you use the same sequence to end the string literal.

So just use something different the `$$` on the outside:

```
DO $doblock$
DECLARE tran_year RECORD;
BEGIN
   FOR tran_year IN SELECT * FROM tbale1 loop
       EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT unique_cons$$aaf1c86 UNIQUE (samplecol)';
   END LOOP;
END $doblock$;
```